# React Native package.json versions

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a React Native project created a month ago, using `create-react-native-app` command.

The `package.json` contents are as follow:

```
{
  "name": "TestApp2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "jest-expo": "~19.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^19.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.46.1"
  }
}
```

When I create a project today, the `package.json` is as follow:

```
{
  "name": "NewApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.5.0",
    "jest-expo": "^21.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^21.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.4"
  }
}
```

Please note that the versions of `react-native-scripts`, `jest-expo` and `expo` are different. My question is, how can I upgrade the version? Should I just change the version number manually?

I tried to use:

```
$ npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
$ react-native-git-upgrade
```

But it does not upgrade the versions.

I also tried:

```
$ npm update
$ react-native upgrade
```

But both commands don't update the versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just manually update the versions in your `package.json` file and the re-run `npm install`.

Comment: Any alternative way to let `npm update` upgrade the versions specified in `package.json` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using expo,
you can also use its upgrade functions.

So just run `expo upgrade` in the root directory, look here
[expo doc](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/expo-cli/#expo-upgrade)

Comment: at the moment the question was asked, the command did not exist yet. But yes, it should be the correct answer for modern days.

Answer (score -1):

{

```
"react-native-scripts": "1.1.0",
"jest-expo": "~19.0.0",
```

},

try edit with new version,and run "rm -rf node_modules && npm install" in your project!